# MM/DD/YY regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to catched the "asd06/05/04" and "06/05/04". I am using for

```
 m/[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]/
```

for this question.

```
   if($word =~ "m/[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]/"){
        print "$word => catched";}

    else{
        print "$word => not catched\n";
    }
```

How can I do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Put a parenthesis around it?

Comment: it still doesn't work.

Comment: The results goes to `$1`

Comment: mate that is complicated. Try this (\w+)?\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}

Comment: I am sorry but I have same problem "asd06/06/04 => not catched". Why?. Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: Your code is very hard to read for one thing. Also I see "/[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9]". I am not sure why are you trying to do a alternative here. This is not a POSIX regex. You should use more pearly syntax for regex, since it has better readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your regular expression is a bit complicated, Try this:

```
$word = "asd06/05/04";
if( $word =~ /(\w+)?\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/ ){
  print "$word => catched \n";
} else{
  print "$word => not catched\n";
}
```